# Sending and receiving data to PHP from Python

Tags: php, python, sql

I am working on a project that requires a python client to execute functions and send data to a PHP server. To clarify, the python program is on a client computer, the PHP script is hosted on a webserver (24hosting). I need the python script to be able to get data from an SQL server  hosted on the same site as the PHP server. I have already written code to get the SQL table data using PHP, I just need a way to get that data into python.

I am hoping the process will look like this:

- Data in SQL Table
- Get data using PHP
- Use python on remote computer to recieve data from PHP

Any advice on how to go about this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) api library in Python. You can use this library to let your python client make web based calls to our php code hosted in a web-server.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to send the data from the PHP webserver in some easy-to-parse format such as JSON. Python has good  [parsing libraries for JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), and for [sending/receiving HTTP requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest). The later is not part of the standard library, but can be downloaded using `pip` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from PHP to Python via JSON like this.

PHP script `myscript.php` reads a database table into a PHP array which is then encoded as JSON:

```
$fields = array('pkey', 'name', 'occupation');
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row_data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row_data[] = $row;
}
$rowfields = array('cols' => $fields, 'rows' => $row_data);
$json_data = json_encode($rowfields);
echo $json_data;
```

Then on a local computer running python:

```
import json
import urllib2
url = r'http://www.mysite/myscript.php'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
remote_data = json.load(response)
```

In this example, `remote_data` is a python dictionary with our server data.